# How do I set up varying sized images to occupy all the space between them

Tags: html, css, image, css-float, fluid-images

Hi I am trying to create a photo display where I can list multiple images of varying size in a way that would allow them to fit in the various spaces without leaving blank spots. an example of what I am trying to achieve can be observed on this site: http://www.morgannorman.com/

Here is a preview of my html and how I have set up the images:

`<div class="feature-list">
                <div class="feat" id="one">
                    <img src="galleries/display/pic1.jpg">
                    <img src="galleries/display/pic6.jpg">
                    <img src="galleries/display/pic3.jpg">
                    <img src="galleries/display/pic4.jpg">
                    <img src="galleries/display/pic5.jpg">
                    <img src="galleries/display/pic2.jpg">
                    <img src="galleries/display/pic3.jpg">
                    <img src="galleries/display/pic4.jpg">
                    <img src="galleries/display/pic1.jpg">
                    <img src="galleries/display/pic2.jpg">
                    <img src="galleries/display/pic3.jpg">
                    <img src="galleries/display/pic4.jpg">
                </div>
            </div>`

and my CSS:

```
.feature-list {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10% 0;
}

.feat {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.feat img {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the masonary plugin: 
http://masonry.desandro.com/

After you include your plugin init it like this

```
$('.feat').masonry({
  columnWidth: 200,
  itemSelector: 'img'
});
```

Comment: Can I not achieve this without the use of JS?